# to help aid - is it correct?

Tags: verbs, redundancy

I've seen a sentence

> Your donation will help aid flood victims.

A dictionary says "aid = to help".
So the sentence is "Your donation will help help flood victims."

I was wondering if "help aid" is correct or it means something special.
Why not just

> "Your donation will help flood victims."

or

> "Your donation will aid flood victims."

Comment: Good point. 'Help aid' in this type of context is just one of those pointless redundancies that most of us have become so used to that we don't even notice them. Sometimes it takes a non-native speaker to force us to notice how silly they are.  :)

Comment: As 'help support' would not be considered a redundancy (being interpreted as 'provide part of the support for / needed by'; 'aid aiders'), 'help aid' will almost certainly be interpreted the same way. But as Erik says, it's a peculiar usage, though probably an idiom by now (half a million Google hits for "help aid", though admittedly way over half of the first 20 hits are false positives). There are 31.6 million Google hits for "help support". "Help help" is not strictly wrong, but sounds weird without padding: _Help Macnurses help others_.

Comment: I agree with Edwin. There's nothing really redundant about this. There's an implicit, deleted pronoun in the sentence: “Your donation will help [us to] aid flood victims”. (Incidentally, you don't _meet_ sentences in English unless you run into them in the street and go up and say hello to them. In normal circumstances, you _come across_ sentences.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between "Your donation will help aid flood victims" and "Your donation will aid flood victims."

It's the same difference that there is between "Your family will help build the house" and "Your family will build the house." That is, in the first version of each sentence, "help" signifies that what you're doing is a part of a greater whole, with more people involved. Of course, "build a house" has a more definite scope and endpoint than "aid flood victims," but the extra "help", to my ear, works to portray the individual effort as a single element of a larger effort.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is need of improvement. I would recast it as "Your donation will help ***to*** aid flood victims."